# Persistence Error Message: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for the find operation

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, netbeans

I am trying to use Netbeans 7.01 to follow a tutorial on JSF 2.0 and JPA. I am using oracle XE and JDBC_6. I used JSF pages from entities wizard to generate my JSF pages. Everything works fine as I can retrive data from the database and display them. However when I attempt to create or update a record in the database, I get this error:

> An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for the find operation

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Which bit of null PK passed in to "find" don't you understand ? (and compare it with what you do actually pass in to the em.find method).

Answer (score 10):

This basically means that you did the following:

```
Entity entity = em.find(Entity.class, null);
```

Note that the PK is `null` here. To fix your problem, just make sure that it's **not** `null`.

Answer (score 4):

This may be because you are running a find operation on an entity that has not been persisted yet. In which situation, the @ID field (if it is autogenerated), will not have a value, ie. it will be null. You are then trying to find the entity, and as @BalusC points out, you are sending a null value into your find method.

Answer (score 2):

It means that when you are trying to persist an entity you are sending the PK of the entity as null.

So you have three options:

- Define manually the PK for the Entity.
- If your database uses a type like Serial (Informix, MS SQLSERVER, etc) then the value will by autoincremented by the RDMS you can use IDENTITY strategy, so now you can pass null value for your entity's pk.

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Inventory implements Serializable { 
          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
          private long id;
  ```
- If your database uses a sequences for generate pks (Oracle, Postgresql, etc) then the value be provided by a sequence so you can use:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Inventory implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(generator="InvSeq")
      @SequenceGenerator(name="InvSeq",sequenceName="INV_SEQ", allocationSize=5)
      private long id;
  ```

For more information you can see: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey